# How to add new Column in Products Listing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-column-grid, product-listing

## I am trying to add one more column on the product listing.

[image]

I have tried to with below code.

> **_listing.less**

```
/
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .page-products {
        .products-grid {
            .product-item {
                width: 100%/3;
            }
        }
    }

    .page-products.page-layout-1column {
        .products-grid {
            .product-item {
                width: 100%/5;
            }
        }
    }
    // I added this 
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-left,
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-right {
        .products-grid .product-item {
            width: 100%/5;
        }
    }
 // Till here

    .page-products.page-layout-3columns {
        .products-grid {
            .product-item {
                width: 100%/2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me where I am going wrong.